# Tell me why Scala says: "type META has incompatible type"

Tags: scala

After failing to get the desired result with generics only, I decided to try types instead. Unfortunately I got stuck at an even earlier stage then with the generics. This is my code:

```
trait Base[B <: Base[B]] {
    type META = Meta[B]
    def meta: META
}

trait Meta[B <: Base[B]]

trait EnumBase[B <: EnumBase[B]]
    extends Base[B] with Ordered[B] {
    override type META = EnumMeta[B]
}

trait EnumMeta[B <: EnumBase[B]]
    extends Meta[B] with Iterable[B]
```

And I get from the Scala compiler that "type META has incompatible type" in EnumBase. Why is that? EnumBase *is* a Base, and EnumMeta *is* a Meta, therefore EnumMeta[EnumBase] *is* compatible with Meta[Base] IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this...

```
trait Base[B <: Base[B]] {
    type META <: Meta[B]
    def meta: META
}

trait Meta[B <: Base[B]]

trait EnumBase[B <: EnumBase[B]]
    extends Base[B] with Ordered[B] {
    type META = EnumMeta[B]
}

trait EnumMeta[B <: EnumBase[B]]
    extends Meta[B] with Iterable[B]
```

... it compiles, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot override a type member which is completely set, you can put stronger constraints on it (it the type had been abstract, with `type Meta <: Meta[B]` for instance), not dispense with previous constraints altogether.

What you did would be unsound if allowed. You would have ways to change method signature at will in subclasses, provided you had used type aliases in the base class (where what you had is just that, a type alias)

On the question of generic vs type member, it is not a clear cut question, but I think type member are definitely better when they do not appear in the public interface of the trait, in which case the client should not be bothered to mention it. If it does, (here in the result of `meta`), I would consider generics first.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the syntax. Coming from Java, I normally try generics first. But as my hierarchy grows, the complexity of the generics parameters definition become exponential where the complexity of abstract types stay linear, so I'm starting to think that they are in fact easier to use then generics.